# How to deal with expressions from another culture using Datatable/Datacolumn

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I have some code in my codebase that evaluates an expression that gets passed to it using the [Datatable method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns) because [insert historical reasons here]. A short version of the method is below.

When my application is running in a non US/AU/UK locale like Spain where periods are swapped for commas in floating point numbers, the code doesn't work.

Is there a way I can make the Datatable method more culture-aware? Or am I stuck with parsing my data into invariantcultures before things get that far?

```
    void Main()
    {
        // This works
        CompareInACulture("en-US"); // US English

        // This doesn't
        CompareInACulture("es-ES"); // Spanish

    }

    // This is testing code for the purposes of exploring the issue
    // With this code I am comparing the value 1.1 with 1 and seeing if the first value is larger
    // than the second. The code fails when in Spanish locale.
    public void CompareInACulture(string cultureCode)
    {
        var value1 = 1.1;
        var value2 = 1;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cultureCode);

        var compareString = value1.ToString() + ">" + value2.ToString();

        // My current approach is to use an invariantCulture here, but I'm not satisfied it is the best approach
        // var compareString = value1.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ">" + value2.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        // I'd rather do something with the ExpressionEval class to let it know that the string it is workign with is from another culture.

        Console.WriteLine($"Now comparing {compareString}");

        var evaluator = new ExpressionEval();
        var result1 = evaluator.Evaluate(compareString, out var passOrFail);
        Console.WriteLine($"Evaluate returned {result1} and passOrFail is {passOrFail}.");
    }

    // This is a simplified version of the class that's doing the actual job. I can tweak this, but not radically change it.
    public class ExpressionEval
    {
        string _lastErrorText = "";
        public string LastErrorText => _lastErrorText;

        public bool Evaluate(string psExpression, out bool pbResult)
        {
            pbResult = false;

            try
            {
                var loDataTable = new DataTable();
                var loDataColumn = new DataColumn("Eval", typeof(bool), psExpression);
                loDataTable.Columns.Add(loDataColumn);
                loDataTable.Rows.Add(0);
                pbResult = (bool)(loDataTable.Rows[0]["Eval"]);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // do stuff
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I was hopeful that the DataTable.locale would assist, but setting it doesn't seem to achieve anything. The remarks at [this Microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.locale(v=vs.110).aspx) say in part "In columns that contain expressions, the InvariantCulture is used. The CurrentCulture is ignored."

Comment: It looks like somebody is trying to take a DateTime and parsing as if it is a string to get another DateTime.  If you already have a DateTime it is in a generic format that doesn't require a culture.  The DateTime is stored in a computer in UTF as a number.  The number when converted to a string uses a the default the PC timezone and culture to display the datetime.  Also when using Datetime.Parse() it is converted from string to DateTime using as default the culture and timezone of the PC.  Once in DateTime format no further conversion is required.

Comment: @jdweng this is not date time related. There are no dates or times in the code sample. This code is taking an expression that is a string (e.g. "1.1>2" and evaluating it as a boolean (is it true or false.)